# Infinite redirect loop on nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, redirect, infinite-loop, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server which runs nginx and shiny server. Shiny runs on :3838.
While the https version of shiny is loading without any problems from port 8443, the site on :80 gets in an infinite redirect loop.

This is the configuration.

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
   server_name **mydomain**;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

   }
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name **mydomain**;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/**mycertificate**.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/**mykey**.key;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://**mydomain**;
       proxy_redirect http://**mydomain**/ https://$host/;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_read_timeout 20d;
   }
}

server {
   listen 8443 ssl;
   server_name **mydomain**;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/**mycertificate**.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/**mykey**.key;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://**mydomain**:3838;
       proxy_redirect http://**mydomain**:3838/ https://$host/;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_read_timeout 20d;
   }
}
```

I can't understand what might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: The `server` listening on port 80 redirects to https, the `server` listening on port 443. This `server` proxies back to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

According to Richard Smith's comment, I removed the server section that listens to 443 and the issue was fixed.